# How do I use a wildcard with a RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, opencart

I have a website that I limit access to by IP address, however there are a few services that need to "poke through" for any IP address. They begin with:

`/index.php?route=extension/openbay/amazon/order`

I was using the following RewriteCond line to hopefully allow these which it sort of does but looking at the logs, sometimes some are being failed with a 403 error.

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^route=extension/openbay/.*$`

I suspect that its the wildcard at the end not capturing all that it needs to perhaps?

Comment: QUERY_STRING does not include the page.  So if a user types in `/SOMETHING.HTML?route=extension/openbay/amazon/order`, your RewriteCond would trigger.    You could restrict it further with another RewriteCond on REQUEST_URI.  To help further, you should post the requests that return a 403.